# Is there anyway/plugin we can trigger a build only at particular time and should not be able to trigger any other time?

Tags: jenkins

I have created my job and want to trigger build daily at 11am and in any other time I should not be able to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Go to “**Build Triggers**” section in jenkins and under that Check “**Poll SCM**”, here you can create cron jon for your pipeline trigger.

For you query you can give somethind like below in the Poll SCM schedule box:

```
0 11 * * *
```

Jenkins used a cron expression, and the different fields are:

> MINUTES Minutes in one hour (0-59)
>
> HOURS Hours in one day (0-23)
>
> DAYMONTH Day in a month (1-31)
>
> MONTH Month in a year (1-12)
>
> DAYWEEK Day of the week (0-7) where 0 and 7 are sunday

For more info please visit [here](https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-poll)

Comment: But he is still able to trigger it manually "in any other time"!

Comment: you can revoke the access to build from the user

Answer (score 0):

To add on the given answer , you can also add a simple bash script to check the time and exit or do the same in the jenkins pipeline